# Group By that chains back and forth across two fields

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, group-by

I have a setup that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MessageGrouping(MessageGroupingId bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
                             StoredMessageId bigint, MessageGroupId bigint)

INSERT INTO [MessageGrouping]([StoredMessageId], [MessageGroupId])
SELECT 1, 301 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 302 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 302 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 303 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 304 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 305 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 305 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 303
GO
```

I need this to return groups (of `StoredMessageId`s) like this:

```
[1,2,6], [3, 7], [4]
```

> **Update:** *The logic for the first grouping is like this:*  `StoredMessageId` 1 has `MessageGroupId` 301 and 302 on it.  But `MessageGroupId` 302 also has `StoredMessageId` 2 on it.  So `StoredMessageId` 2 has to be included in the group.
>
> But `StoredMessageId` 2 also has `MessageGroupId` 305 on it.  And `MessageGroupId` 305 has `StoredMessageId` 6, so it is also included in the group.

I tried this in LinqPad and came up empty.  A simple `MessageGroupings.GroupBy(x=>x.MessageGroupId)` only groups by `MessageGroupId` (as expected).

Adding in `StoredMessageId`s (`MessageGroupings.GroupBy(x=>new {x.MessageGroupId, x.StoredMessageId})` just puts each row in its own group.

Is there a way to do chained grouping in Linq like I am looking for?  I am also fine to do it in SQL.

I would like to be able to use this in a Micro ORM like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), but if I need Entity Framework I can do that too.

Comment: I really don't understand how the groups are made

Comment: How would write a SQL statement to get the results?

Comment: @AdrianIftode - I updated my question to explain how the groups are made.  As for how to write this in SQL, I am also drawing a blank.  I am hoping that someone who know either Linq or SQL really well can help me out.  As I indicated in my Question, I am good with an answer that is in Linq or SQL.  (This is not a "Translate this SQL into Linq" question.)

Comment: I think that to do this in SQL, you would need a recursive query or a `while` loop. Which means you can't do it directly in LINQ. But maybe your `GroupBy()` plus some postprocessing might be enough? Also, what SQL server are you using? MS SQL Server?

Comment: Oh, this is evil...  What is this being used for?  Normally, I'd want to use something like a recursive CTE (which can be used to deal with tree structures), but they can't handle cyclical references (CTE A is referenced in CTE B, which references CTE A) - ie, your situation.  If you know the maximum depth, you could probably use a join-per level.  Either way, you may be looking at row by (agonizing) row.

Comment: @svick - I am targeting Sql Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3):

Okay - contrary to what I thought, you *can* do this with a single recursive CTE.
Not that it's pretty...

Please note that all testing was done on DB2, which does not have a way to return arrays in-row.  I don't know if SQL Server can (so you may have to parse results).  I do **NOT** recommend attempting to do this with Linq - if anything, this should be run on the database directly.

```
WITH Mappings(beginId, storedId, groupId, storedPath, groupPath) as (
     SELECT a.StoredMessageId, a.StoredMessageId, a.MessageGroupId,
            a.StoredMessageId + "|", a.MessageGroupId + "|"
     FROM MessageGrouping as a
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM MessageGrouping as b
                       WHERE b.StoredMessageId < a.StoredMessageId
                       AND b.MessageGroupId = a.MessageGroupId)
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM MessageGrouping as b
                     WHERE b.MessageGroupId < a.MessageGroupId
                     AND b.StoredMessageId = a.StoredMessageId)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT a.beginId, a.storedId, b.MessageGroupId,
            a.storedPath, a.groupPath + b.MessageGroupId + "|"
     FROM Mappings as a
     JOIN MessageGrouping as b
     ON b.StoredMessageId = a.storedId
     AND b.MessageGroupId <> a.groupId
     AND a.groupPath NOT LIKE "%" + b.MessageGroupId + "%"
     UNION ALL
     SELECT a.beginId, a.StoredMessageId, a.groupId,
            a.storedPath + b.StoredMessageId + "|", a.groupPath
     FROM Mappings as a
     JOIN MessageGrouping as b
     ON b.MessageGroupId = a.groupId
     AND b.StoredMessageId <> a.storedId
     AND a.storedPath NOT LIKE "%" + b.StoredMessageId + "%"),

     Result_Rows (ids, num) as (
     SELECT storedPath, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY beginId
                              ORDER BY LENGTH(storedPath) DESC)
     FROM Mappings)
SELECT ids
FROM Result_Rows
WHERE num = 1
```

Yields `ids` of:

```
1|2|6|
3|7|  
4|
```

Comment: Looks interesting. I will try it on my sql server tomorrow.  Thanks for the answer!